# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sumArray

Tags: javascript, foreach, console

I keep getting an error message in my web page console when testing out this loop; "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sumArray".

My first loop worked just fine and resulted in a "true" message.

```
//*** isUniform() ***

function isUniform(arr){
    var first = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i] !== first){
        return false;
      } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

But my second loop worked just fine and resulted in a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sumArray" message.

```
// *** sumArray() ***

function sumArray(arr){
    var total = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(element){
      total += element; 
    });
    return total;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Please post an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Perhaps *sumArray* is in a script element or file that hasn't been loaded when the call is made? Function declarations are processed before any code is executed, so this can only occur if *sumArray* is in a later or inaccessible script element.